# increase/decrease the upper/lower bound of something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am writing a technical document and I wanted to describe that a certain method or approach will improve the performance when the performance is bad but will undermine the performance when the performance is really good. In other words it will make the upper bound of the performance lower but also make the lower bound of the performance higher.

I wonder if this sentence sounds natural or grammatically correct?

> it decreases the upper bound of the performance while increases the lower bound of the performance

Also is there any other way to describe this behavior?

Comment: It should be "...while increasING the lower bound" instead of "increases" and I don't think it's necessary to say "of the performance" again. Other than that, it's not really the most natural or conversational phrasing but it sounds appropriate for a technical document. I prefer the way you explained it in the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 1):

> it decreases the upper bound of the performance while increases the lower bound of the performance

I would avoid this for two reasons:

- I feel it has a strange tone to it: somehow comical
- in case the audience is not guaranteed to have received an academic level of education — for example me — this sentence comes across as some scientific meta-language, whose meaning — without the explanation of the context in your post — I would have hard time deciphering. It's abstracted so far, that it has lost its utility for me.

Due to the aforementioned lack in academic education background, I may well be unaware of an otherwise very fitting language pattern that could offer a better solution here. There might even exist a very specific term describing this kind of dynamic, but then again, I don't know where to look for it.

Yet, allow me to try something:

> While this method has the potential to impact an under-performing
> system positively, it will introduce a detrimental effect when applied
> to an otherwise optimally working system.